# Python append to json dict inline

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
>>> salaries = '{"Alfred" : 300, "Jane" : 400 }'
>>> sal = json.loads(salaries)["Hritik"]=0
>>> sal
0
>>> sal = json.loads(salaries)
>>> sal["Hritik"]=0
>>> sal
{'Alfred': 300, 'Jane': 400, 'Hritik': 0}
>>> type(json.loads(salaries))
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(sal)
<class 'dict'>
```

Why can't I append to the `dict` returned by `json.loads` inline as I can do with the dict sal ?
Doesn't `json.loads` returns just a `dict` and that should be same as any other dict ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment statement `x = y = z` implies that both `x` and `y` will take on the value of `z`.

As an example, look at the byte code for the assignment `a = b = 2`:

```
In [45]: import dis; dis.dis(compile('a = b = 2', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              3 DUP_TOP
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              7 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

With `4 STORE_NAME`, a is assigned first to 2, followed by `7 STORE_NAME` where `b` is then assigned to the same value, 2.

So, with

```
sal = json.loads(salaries)["Hritik"] = 0
```

`sal` receives the value `0`. Also, a temporary variable is created when you call `json.loads` and that is modified, following which the reference is lost.

In order to get this to work, you'll need to break this up into 2 parts, as you have already done.

```
sal = json.loads(salaries)
sal['Hritik'] = 0
```

Comment: "Assignments in python occur from right to left" isn't quite accurate, because `sal` actually gets assigned before `json.loads(salaries)["Hritik"]`. Evaluation order in Python assignment statements is much more of a confusing mess than it first appears.

Comment: @user2357112 Where can I look this up?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

Comment: Check: `import dis; dis.dis(compile('a=b=2', '', 'exec'))`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks! Hope you don't mind, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I append to the dict returned by json.loads inline as I can do with the dict sal ?

You can, and you do, but then you just discard that dict. It doesn't have any effect on the `salaries` variable, and you didn't assign the dict to `sal`. You assigned 0 to `sal`.

When you assign `sal = json.loads(salaries)`, that makes a new dict, unrelated to the first dict, and then you actually assign the new dict to `sal`. Modifications to this new dict are still visible when you view the dict through `sal`.